# An efficient way of showing/hiding a series of elements according to ranges

Tags: jquery, hide, show

Say you filter a long series of photos of people according to age ranges (20-25, 26-30, 31-35...). Given that a user can permute to any range they want how could you make the showing/hiding efficient?

Edit: Here's my current code:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="http://..." age=""/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var str = '';

$("#ageSelector option:selected").each(
    function () {
        str += $(this).attr("value") + "";
    }
);

$('.photo').each(
    function() {

        var age = parseInt( $(this).attr("age") );

        switch( str ){

            case '18to24':
                if( age <= 24 ){
                    $(this).show();
                }

                if( age > 24 ) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                break;
            case '25to35':
                if( age >= 25 || age <= 35 ) {
                    $(this).show();
                }

                if( age < 25 || age > 35 ){
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                break;
            case '36to45':
                if( age < 36 || age > 45 ){
                    $(this).hide();
                }

                if( age >= 36 || age <= 45 ){
                    $(this).show();
                }
                break;
            case '45to50':
                if( age < 45 || age > 50 ){
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                if( age >= 45 || age <= 50 ){
                    $(this).show();
                }
                break;
            case 'moreThan50':
                if( age < 50 ){
                    $(this).hide();
                }

                if( age >= 50 ) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                $(this).show();
        }


    }
);
```

Comment: Can you provide any code snippets? Otherwise I'd say something like `if(number($(this).data("age")) <= maxVal && number($(this).data("age")) >= minVal)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're storing age on the image, so I'll just assume that you have an HTML5-compliant data attribute on your IMG tag.  It's also unclear how you're getting the range of acceptable values.

You haven't yet provided details on when all of this is happening.  I'll assume it's on the change of your drop down.

```
$('#ageSelector').change(function() {
    //Parse out min and max values from your drop down

    var range = $(this).find('option:selected').val().split("to");
    var min = parseInt(range[0]);
    var max = parseInt(range[1]);

    //To show just elements in the range

    $('img.photo').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).data('age') >= min && $(this).data('age') <= max;
    }).show();

    //To show elements in the range and hide all others

    $('img.photo').each(function() { 
        $this = $(this);
        $this.toggle($this.data('age') >= min && $(this).data('age') <= max);
    });
});
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that. At the moment I'm storing age as a separate variable (age="32") but I'm looking into changing that into a class (class="31to35"). The ranges are defined in the options of a select.

Comment: Updated.  Hopefully it's closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: It is. Thanks a ton. In passing, does using a more precise 'img.photo' offer any advantage over using a simple class selector?

Comment: Absolutely!  Good question.  Speed order: ID selection (#someid) is faster than element selection (img) is faster than class selection (.someclass) is faster than random attribute selection ([foo=bar]).  General tips: Always use an ID if you can, at least to provide context (#foo img), and always make your right-most clause as specific as possible, so `#foo .class` is slower than `#foo img.class`.  If my answers have resolved your problem, please be sure to mark it as the answer!

Comment: Oh, and as another comment, don't use custom attributes like that "age" one you're currently using.  Make it HTML5-compliant, following the form: `data-someAttribute="value"`.  So, `data-age="10"`.  The advantage is not only compliance, but in jQuery you can then use .data('age') rather than .attr('age').

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to provide an exact answer without you providing more details of exactly what you're looking for, but is [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/aASuA/3/) along the right lines? Change the value in the `select` element to filter the `div` elements based on the selection.

It uses the jQuery `filter` function to narrow down the selection based on the selected values, and hides all non-matching elements.

Comment: You make a classic boolean mistake: why have an if statement with boolean return values when you can just return the result of the if statement's test?  `return $(this).attr("id") >= vals[0] && $(this).attr("id") <= vals[1];`

Comment: @James Allardice: That's the sort of thing I'm looking for and much more concise. I haven't come accross filter() yet (relatively new to jQuery) and will give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can have your images in a table ( and the age ) like :

```
var imgs= [ ["http://site/img1.jpg",32],
            ["http://site/img2.jpg",27],
            ["http://site/img5.jpg",24],
            ["http://site/img9.jpg",22] ];
```

And you have a container `<div id="container"></div>`, you could do a function like :

```
function loadRange(a,b){
  for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++)
    {
    if(imgs[i][1]>=a && imgs[i][1]<=b)
        {
            if(imgs[i][0]==null) $("#img"+i).show();
            else
            {
                $("#container").append('<img src="'+encodeURI(imgs[i][0])+'" id="img'+i+'" />');
                imgs[i][0]= null;
            }
        }
        else if(imgs[i][0]==null) $("#img"+i).hide();
    }
}
```

and call `loadRange(20,24)` to load 20 to 24.

( to load only image once when needed )